# Show Div when scrolled to then hide when its not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

Normally I would do this by setting the div to fade in by a set number of pixels from the top. Like the example below. But my problem is one of my content fields has a height that is dynamic so it constantly changes. One time it's 200 pixels long the next its 500. So I want to know how to have a div fade in by detecting if another div is in the viewport. Anyone have an idea how to do this?

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 800) {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's 5 examples (http://www.sitepoint.com/5-jquery-viewport-plugins/).  These rely on using a selector like 'isInViewport' (e.g. `$('img:isInViewport')`) to do something based on whether it's in view or not.  If you want to write your own, you'll need to use Javascript to get the boundingRectangle of the element and work out whether that's inside the visible viewport.

Answer (score 0):

try various combinations with jquerys `.offset().top` or `.position().top`

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > $('yourdiv').offset().top) {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
  }
});
```